# Why does the application exit when closing a QMessageBox with an invisible parent window?

Tags: c++, qt, qapplication

This is a boiled down simple example:

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
 
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTimer>
 
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow();
private slots:
    void OnTimer();
private:
    MainWindow(const MainWindow&);
    QTimer timer;
};
 
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QMessageBox>
 
MainWindow::MainWindow() : QMainWindow(nullptr)
{
    connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::OnTimer);
    timer.start(2000);
}

void MainWindow::OnTimer()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "", "2 seconds over");
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QString>
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow win;

    if (argc >= 2 && !QString(argv[1]).compare("show"))
    {
        win.show();
    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.pro

```
SOURCES += main.cpp mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS += mainwindow.h
QT += widgets
TARGET = mainwindow
```

When executing this example with command line parameter `show` the MainWindow is visible, and every 2 seconds, a message box pops up. That's what I would expect.

But when executing without a command line parameter, the MainWindow (intentionally) is not visible. In this case the message box only pops up once, followed by finishing the message loop and exiting.

What has to be changed to keep the application running, popping up message boxes every 2 seconds even if the MainWindow is not visible?

Comment: If this reproduces your problem: `QTimer timer; QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [](){QMessageBox::information(nullptr, "", "2 seconds over");}); timer.start(2000);`. Then as a tip, you can simplify your example further, no need for multiple files, just `main.cpp`, and no need to mention passing parameters to the executable, that can be replaced with hard-coded variables. This is assuming I understood your case correctly.